# Python Socket bound on 0.0.0.0, can't connect via 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I have a Windows XPSP3 machine running a Python XMLRPCServer bound to 0.0.0.0:8000, but when I try to connect via an httplib HTTPConnection on address 127.0.0.1:8000, I get a socket.connection error, errno 10107 (Unknown Error).

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>netstat -ano

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       940
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1244
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3624
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10049          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1028         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2644
  TCP    192.168.80.132:139     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  UDP    0.0.0.0:445            *:*                                    4
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                                    696
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1025           *:*                                    1096
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                                    696
  UDP    127.0.0.1:123          *:*                                    1040
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    1252
  UDP    192.168.80.132:123     *:*                                    1040
  UDP    192.168.80.132:137     *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.80.132:138     *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.80.132:1900    *:*                                    1252

C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib
>>> h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1:8000')
>>> h1.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10107] A system call that should never fail has failed
>>> h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection('192.168.80.132:8000')
>>> h1.connect()
>>>
```

**Edit:** It's in the code block, but I forgot to actually mention it.  If I try to connect via the machines's IP address (192.168.80.132), it connects successfully.

For more context, this is actually occurring in an instance of the Cuckoo Sandbox analyzer.py script, but I've been able to recreate the error as above, so I don't think this is an issue with Cuckoo, but with Windows Sockets.  I appreciate any help you can provide with this.

Comment: If you do 'ping -a 127.0.0.1' does it reverse successfully to your hostname?

Comment: It resolves to localhost, but not my hostname (winxp-vm).

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>ping -a 127.0.0.1
    
    Pinging localhost [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
    
    Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    
    Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
        Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
    
    C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>

Comment: Try opening a DOS window on the machine and running "telnet 127.0.0.1 8000".  If telnet connects, then the server is listening on port 8000 and so the problem is probably on the client (httplib) side of things.  If you get "connection refused", on the other hand, the server isn't listening on port 8000 so the problem is on the server side.

Comment: `C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8000.
The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Attempting to telnet to its assigned ip address (192.168.80.132 8000) is successful though.

Comment: I've got a workaround that works for me at the moment.  In the Cuckoo analyzer script `"http://127.0.0.1:8000"` is hardcoded into the socket connection setup routine.  I changed this so it is now `"http://"+socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())+":8000"`.  This returns the assigned IP address rather than the loopback address, which seems to make Windows happy.  I don't consider this to be an answer because I figure the Cuckoo code should work, and it is rather probably an issue with my guest Windows OS setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the result of another system modification I had made.  This was on malware analysis sandbox, and I had installed a tool for monitoring low-level network traffic.  Even though I had uninstalled the tool, it had installed a Layered Service Provider that continued to persist.  I removed those LSPs, and everything functions as it should.